# Distribution conditional on the Sum of IID Normals

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Assume I have iid $\varepsilon_{i}\sim \mathbb{N}(0,1)$ for $i=1,\dots,T$,

What is the marginal distribution of $\varepsilon_{i}$, conditional on $\sum_{i=1}^{T}\varepsilon_{i}=C$, i.e

$$ F(\varepsilon_{i}|\sum_{j=1}^{T}\varepsilon_{j}=C) $$

Thanks!

Comment: You surely know how to get $p(x|y)$ in terms of $p(y|x)$ (Bayes' theorem), no? Have your tried it?

Comment: Oh that's useful! I dont know why I did not think about it

Comment: But if my goal was to actually draw from this distribution, how would you do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "draw from this distribution"? You want to simulate it?

Comment: I would like to get draws of $\varepsilon_{i}$ conditional on the sum of them being equal to a constant. 

The only thing that I have thought is:

It is easy to figure out the distribution of the first one, I draw it. Then I redefine the constant $C1=C-\varepsilon_{1}$, until I arrive to the last one which is determinate.

Comment: But you are insterested in generating, not single (marginal) values, but joint $(e_1,e_2 \cdots e_T)$ vectors ? If so, you should not ask about the marginal distribution.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243260/sample-random-variables-conditional-on-their-sum